# laravel - failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: laravel, stream

sometimes without any reason, on random page I get this error:

```
ErrorException
include(/home/merolek/websites/kolejnastronka/vendor/composer/../symfony/finder/Symfony/Component/Finder/Iterator/DateRangeFilterIterator.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Till today my solution was refresh the site, but i am a bit angry on that right now.

Comment: Is something like `composer update` running in the background?

Comment: Hmm, my script auto scrape data from tmdb, but i am using local settings right now. Script i am using is MTDb

Answer (score 1):

The solution was really easy. I didn't move all files corectly on FTP...